# C# setting array to method return type is returning null

Tags: c#, methods, return-type

I'm trying to set an int array to one that a method in another class should return. However no matter what way I try to set the return array, it returns null instead and crashes the program.

```
int[] xCord = populateGrid.giveMeObstacle();
```

Should set xCord to the return value of giveMeObstacle, right?

This is the return code in another class:

```
public int getLevel()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("you got to here");
        return 1;
    }

    public int[] giveMeObstacle()
    {
        int[] test = new int[] { 2, 3 };

        if(getLevel() == 1)
        {
            int[] test1 = new int[] { 2, 3 };
            test1 = test;
        }
        else
        {
            int[] test2 = new int[] { 2, 3 };
            test2 = test;
        }

        return test;
    }
```

Comment: When you say _"This is the return code in another class"_ where / how are you instantiating that class? It's not apparent from the code you have posted.

Comment: We need to know what `populateGrid` is, and what class `giveMeObstacle()` is defined in

Comment: The code you have posted above will return an integer array with 2 and 3 in it, there's no error.

Comment: Shall I post the entire classes of populateGrid and Movement (where the method xCord is in, is)?

Comment: Best to try posting only the relevant parts of them.

Comment: Posting the code that instantiates `populateGrid` would probably be most relevant

Comment: populateGrid is just created as a private class inside the movement class like so: private PopulateGrid populateGrid { get; set; }

Comment: It sounds like you're not instantiating it then... i.e. `populateGrid = new PopulateGrid()`, and if not then it'll be that object which is null, not the result of the method.

Comment: OK yeah that fixed it alright. I think I understand now, thanks!